# Key and cursor glitch in Terminal.app

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, terminal.app

I am having a problem with Terminal. It is triggered when I do something that involves the Command key, Cmd-C, Cmd-V etc. It causes my keyboard actions to not be recognized until I click somewhere with the cursor (within the terminal window). And at the same time it treats the cursor as if I am holding down the shift key. (it highlighs everything between my last 2 clicks).

At first I thought it was just going haywire, but I've found this to be very reproducable. The problem usually persists untill I close all the terminal windows and open a new one.

I have a fresh install of Mountain Lion as of 5 days ago (new ssd), that is when the problem began. This ONLY happens in terminal.
Any ideas what the deal is or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This, along with several other keyboard and trackpad issues that popped up, were because of Jitouch, an app (perf pane really) that allows for extra multi-touch gestures. I've yet to run into anyone else having this problem from this app, but if I turn the app off, the problems go away.